# Use a std::vector as a changeable, fully-populated array?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm using a vector.  For my purposes, I generally need it to have (n) elements which will only be accessed & modified using the index [] operator.

At a certain point, my algorithm will decide it needs more space and that I need to enlarge this vector to say... 2 times it's size.

Is there a way I can double the size and have all of the new space in the vector default initialized with the vector element type?

Basically, instead of manually inserting elements to fill up the capacity after it doubles, I would like its entire capacity to be fully populated and default initialized after the increase.  As far as I know, reserve just reserves space (and doesn't initialize elements in it, so while I could use that and a loop-insert, I was hoping there's a... more fun? way).

So, I want a similar effect to that of creating a new vector with this constructor:

```
std::vector<MyType> vec(2*oldvec.size(), MyType());
```

except I would like to maintain the elements that were already in the vector before it doubled in size as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [std::vector::resize()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/).

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about that >.<  I'll accept when the countdown ends :p

Answer (score 4):

You just need to resize the vector using `resize` : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/

Answer (score 2):

Try `vec.resize(newsize, MyType())`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other answers, the `resize` vector method will set the size of the current vector to the requested value.  Assuming the specified size is larger, it will populate the new vector entries with a copy of the provided default value.

Assuming enough contiguous space is available for the expansion of the vector, this can be more efficient than creating a new, larger vector and copying the contents of the original.

Is the initialization of new elements to a default value necessary?  If not, you can save yourself the trouble, and if the object is not a native type the cost of repeatedly constructing the default, by simply leaving it uninitialized until the vector location is needed. In which case simply add more (uninitialized) storage space to the vector using the `reserve` method, and add new values to the vector as needed, using push/pop routines.

Comment: No, never read or write to elements past what the vector has initialized.  Thats undefined, and will result in surprising behavior.

Comment: Agreed.  Accessing undefined elements is bad and not at all what I intended to suggest.

Comment: Can you clarify that last sentence?  It sounds like that's what you are suggesting.

Comment: The initial poster is looking to double the size of his vector under certain conditions, specifying that the new elements be initialized already.

I was questioning whether they actually needed the default values.  For instance, if a default is being used and will be overwritten with new data later, it might make more sense to simply add more (uninitialized) storage space to the vector and to add new values to the vector as needed, using push/pop routines.